# Constrain generic's object property type

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-typings

Let's assume we have some function which param is string

```
const action = (param: string) => {
    return param;
};
```

And there's a generic type

```
interface Relation<T, K extends keyof T> {
    store: T;
    storeKey: K;
}
```

And function which accepts param of type `Relation` and performs `action`

```
const testFunction = <T, K extends keyof T>({ store, storeKey }: Relation<T, K>) => {
    action(store[storeKey]);
};
```

Now TypeScript error message is `store[storeKey] is not assignable to type string` and I understand why. Is there any way to "deprecate" call of the `testFunction` if `T[K]` is not a string (no typeguards, only static type checking)?

UPD: T can have not only string properties

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `T` you should specify more specific type. i.e. `T extends Record<string, string>`:

```js
const action = (param: string) => {
    return param;
};

interface Relation<T extends Record<string, string>, K extends keyof T> {
    store: T;
    storeKey: K;
}

const testFunction = <T extends Record<string, string>, K extends keyof T>({ store, storeKey }: Relation<T, K>) => {
    action(store[storeKey]);
};
```

Comment: Yeah, but what if T can have not only string properties?

Comment: [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBBlOMCWA7AcwGkRkBnAHgHkA+BAXgQG9gE2EBtIhfBAa1JQAZgioBdALQB+AFyiuYhODgg8AEzIIy2fAVbspCIvrZy8IAG4gYwAL4cByYaLHBgAYyh5tCKA2YmCACGcgCMADSBAEZyAERRsZHsCO5xoQBMAMyJdm6e3ohB7nA4Xv4AFBBBMEEAtnLauIQAlAx0LMkwIHAArjB4CFU1tQDcdmPA+CowQkXoAEogADZBJV4UACrhRkpgKuqajs4b7YHasCByG2PJ510kyHJEY7Z5Xj4q2gBiPXjFpQNGJtttxlKoNJgdIQHpQTjRykwtHALts7iAHghbHJFis1nhgUYaK16KdkkU8eU0Rw0Q9FEFNL8+HgoAB3Ab0pFNAjNF4TT5wH5-CkddhouRQJKi5H3UhxII5WzNNz8wX-LwIs7Sy6+SVsGmyhDxBVK4Aq35qvAa25a8W6pEXB5xdzG4BAA)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is type cast in the end. Even though function check if the given key corresponds to string in `store`, typescript still doesn't know about it.

Comment: [Alternative](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBCMF4YG8BQMMwIYC4YEYAadTAIzwCJSLjMZhL8AmAZhtQF9VVRJYtgUAJbhEMABQAHLACcsAWzzQZQsAHMAlIgB8KEhhkBTKAFcZYGNLnyA3JzupVUQzIBmAwzABKhgDZZhcAAeABVCGABpGEMAD2cwABMIGABrQwBPEFcYEN00OmgQIzwQuwKoIsMIjLwIuy4ecGgYZ2gAMRMwQRELJCCo2PikmGVVNXCQ6LjDROSfUBkE-vDR9W1tcWQRiqMVnaqMmA48H39AsFDwiO0tBDz9bG7wcUKjAG1Xg-SAXWxkzpSYBAAHcLFhkqtNPUHK0oB0uudNg9PngQLRMJ9qulKFh2BwNNxYfCnmAkeVKqj0RhMTUYFQ8QTUETOiSyRj9pTkfssZRgAzUEA)

Comment: This is a bit simpler solution, but we lose key autocomplete.